# Simple groups of order 168

Tags: finite-groups, simple-groups

How would I prove that there is at most one simple group of order 168?

I've already seen that $GL_3(2)$ and $PSL_2(7)$ are simple groups of order 168, and I have seen direct proofs that they are equal.

Now I'd like to show there is only one simple group of that order.

What should I think about to start on doing that? How would you actually prove it?

---

The only thing I know that gives structural results about groups given only its order is Sylow's theorem. So I apply that. Since $168 = 2^3 \cdot 3 \cdot 7$ I know from Sylow's theorem there would be:

- $n_2 | 3 \cdot 7$ and $n_2 \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ so there could be $1,3,7$ or $21$ Sylow 2-subgroups.
- $n_3 | 2^3 \cdot 7$ and $n_3 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ so there could be $1, 4, 7$ or $28$ Sylow 3-subgroups.
- $n_7 | 2^3 \cdot 3$ and $n_7 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$ so there are $1$ or $2^3 = 8$ of these.

I proved a lemma that says if a Sylow subgroup is normal iff it's unique, that proves there cannot be only $1$ 2-Sylow subgroup.

*edit*: So I think I got another useful lemma from the comments and [here](http://www.bath.ac.uk/~masgcs/m38/s9sol.pdf):

**Lemma** Let $G$ be a simple group of order $N$ with $p|N$, then either $|G| \le n_p!$.
*proof*: Let $G$ act by conjugation on its $n_p$ $p$-Sylow subgroups, because they are all conjugate this gives a surjective map $G \to S_{n_p}$, if $n_p$ is not 1 and $|G| > |S_{n_p}|$ the kernel of this map would be a normal subgroup $1 \not = N \unlhd G$.

this leaves us with the possibilities:

- $7$ or $21$ 2-Sylow subgroups.
- $7$ or $28$ 3-Sylow subgroups
- exactly $2^8$ $7$-Sylow-subgroups.

---

Relevant questions:

- [Prove there is no element of order 6 in a simple group of order 168](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71768/prove-there-is-no-element-of-order-6-in-a-simple-group-of-order-168) - This question starts off with more knowledge about the Sylow subgroups than I am able to deduce.
- [Sylow 7-subgroups in a group of order 168](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182189/sylow-7-subgroups-in-a-group-of-order-168) - Shows that 7-Sylow subgroups are normal or have maximal normalizers (I don't understand this)
- [Why $PSL_3(\mathbb F_2)\cong PSL_2(\mathbb F_7)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1401/why-psl-3-mathbb-f-2-cong-psl-2-mathbb-f-7) - Direct proofs of the special isomorphism.

Comment: You mean "they are isomorphic" and "there's only one simple group of order 158 *up to isomorphism*" ...

Comment: Err, where did 158 creep in from?

Comment: @ChrisGodsil, hmm on that note, I have not actually proved this theorem for groups of order 60. Maybe I have to do that first

Comment: I vaguely recall having done this once. Looks like $7$-Sylows might be a good starting point. There are eight of them (as you pointed out). These should probably be in bijective correspondence with the 8 lines the group $PSL_2(7)$ is acting on.

Comment: And yes, I recommend doing it for 60 first. Much easier IIRC :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, thanks, I jumped the gun with this question - I don't know how to do 60 either..

Comment: A hint for 60: If $G$ has a subgroup $H$ of index $<5$, then the permutation action of $G$ on $G/H$ gives a non-trivial homomorphism from $G$ to $S_{[G:H]}$, which is a contradiction. That allows you to exclude some possibilities, and then you will find a subgroup of index exactly five...

Comment: Similarly you can exclude the possibilities $n_3=4$, $n_2=3$ in the 168 case. The group conjugates the Sylows transitively, so if $n_3=4$ we have a non-trivial homomorphism from $G$ to $S_4$, which is a no-no.

Comment: Here's not a hint but the detailed answer: http://math.ucdenver.edu/~tvis/Coursework/Fano.pdf

Comment: Very grateful for all your comments! I will add to my own post once I work the details out.

Comment: If you want to see this problem worked out, check Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra, 3rd Ed. pages 207-212.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oGjcRpSx3HI This video will show you everything

Answer (score 5):

To get you started some rather basic (or even trivial, depends) observations, putting $\,n_p=$ number of Sylow $p-$subgroups , $\,G:=\,$ simple group of order $\,168\,$:

$$168=2^3\cdot 3\cdot7\Longrightarrow n_7=8\;,\;n_3=7,28$$

It can't be $\,n_3=4\,$ as then $\,G\,$ has a subgroup of index 4, which is impossible since this would mean $\,G\,$ is isomorphic with a subgroup of $\,S_4\,$ . For the same reason, it must be $\,n_2=7,\,21\,$...

Perhaps reading [here](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CFcQFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmath.ucdenver.edu%2F~tvis%2FCoursework%2FFano.pdf&ei=eY44UY7qD4v44QSvVw&usg=AFQjCNHwnRZhFIArOJQbtwVLfE6ZqtVNYA&sig2=D0b9sEqzhbDpQjDrSJf8Yw) you'll have have the whole view. Don't worry about the number of pages as the first ones are basic results listed.